# ADB not responding, IntelliJ IDE. [Ubuntu 13.04]

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I keep on getting a ADB not responding please restart or wait error everytime i try to run my app from IntelliJ. I connected to my phone using adb connect 192.... from the terminal. Can anyone help?.

Comment: Do you have Android Device Monitor running? There's usually some contention there when you're trying to access ADB from two different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by running this command in the terminal window    sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386. This installs some libraries which were missing.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, the solution that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

after that installation adb worked perfectly, no need to restart or reinstall anything.

My environment:
InteliJ IDE 12.1.4,
ubuntu 13.04 64bit,
adb 1.0.31